# Нужно написать функцию, которая возвращает первое простое число большее числа num

Tags: python, python-3.x

Нужно написать функцию get_next_prime(num), которая принимает в качестве аргумента натуральное число num и возвращает первое простое число большее числа num

Мой нерабочий код:

```
# объявление функции
def is_prime(num):
    len([i for i in range(1, num+1) if num % i == 0]) == 2
def get_next_prime(num):
    while is_prime(num) == False:
        num += 1
    return

# вызываем функцию
print(get_next_prime(int(input())))
```

Comment: Вы может забыли return num?

Comment: Проверять делители достаточно до квадратного корня из числа, дальше - не имеет смысла

Comment: num не обязателен, интерпретатор все равно 'none' выводит. По поводу квадратного корня, не совсем понимаю о чём вы.

Comment: В is_prime тоже return забыли

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас чуть не в каждой строке ошибка, поэтому разберу несколько фрагментов:

```
def is_prime(num):
    len([i for i in range(1, num+1) if num % i == 0]) == 2
```

Данная функция не возвращает результат проверки. Нужно добавить `return` перед условием.

```
def get_next_prime(num):
    while is_prime(num) == False:
        num += 1
    return
```

Функция ничего не возвращает (т.е. возвращает `None`), нужно возвращать `num`. Кроме того, саму проверку нужно написать по-другому. Никто обычно не сравнивает с `True` и `False`, а пишут просто `if ...` для проверки на `True` или `if not ...` для проверки на `False`. Так код понятнее.

```
print(get_next_prime(int(input())))
```

И даже тут у вас ошибка - нужно вернуть "первое простое число **большее** числа num", но в вашем коде если введённое число простое, то вернётся оно же. Где-то нужно прибавить 1 к введённому числу.

Итого, после коррекции всех ошибок, рабочий код:

```
# объявление функции
def is_prime(num):
    return len([i for i in range(1, num+1) if num % i == 0]) == 2
def get_next_prime(num):
    while not is_prime(num):
        num += 1
    return num

# вызываем функцию
print(get_next_prime(int(input()) + 1))
```

Это я ещё не оптимизировал сам перебор делителей, который, как вам уже написали, можно вести до корня из числа, этого достаточно (но и сравнивать кол-во делителей тогда нужно будет не с 2, а с 1). Потому что если у числа есть делитель больший, чем его корень, то есть и другой делитель, меньший корня и он найдётся при таком переборе до корня. И если сделать обычный цикл, а не *списковое включение*, то при нахождении делителя можно было бы завершить цикл досрочно через `break` или `return`, а не проходить обязательно весь `range`. Оптимизированный код проверки:

```
def is_prime(num):
    for i in range(2, int(num**0.5) + 1):
        if num % i == 0:
            return False
    return True
```